# How to use From clause inside PostgreSQL Update statement

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I am converting SQL stored procedure to PostgreSQL stored function. In this stored function inside `Update` there is `From` clause.

I want to know how to use From inside Update? Because I am getting error   `table name "account" specified more than once`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ETL_Insert_ModifyData( instID numeric)

  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $$ 

        --Account
        UPDATE account
        SET  namount = stg_account.namount, 
             slocation = stg_account.sLocation, 
             ndept_id = stg_account.ndept_id ,
             account.naccount_cpc_mapping_id = stg_account.naccount_cpc_mapping_id
        FROM account 
            INNER JOIN stg_account ON account.naccount_id = stg_account.naccount_id
            INNER JOIN department ON stg_account.ndept_id = department.ndept_id
            INNER JOIN accountcpcmapping ON stg_account.naccount_cpc_mapping_id = accountcpcmapping.naccount_cpc_mapping_id

        WHERE account.ninst_id = instID
            AND department.ninst_id = instID
            AND accountcpcmapping.ninst_id = instID

        --print 'Account completed '    

    $$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `JOIN` condition with `account` table and `stg_account`  to `WHERE` clause. Also, you need  not refer to  `account` in the `SET`.

Further, prefer shorter aliases (like one or 2 letters) rather than using complete table names.

```
UPDATE account
SET
    namount   = stg_account.namount,
    slocation = stg_account.sLocation,
    ndept_id  = stg_account.ndept_id ,
    naccount_cpc_mapping_id = stg_account.naccount_cpc_mapping_id
FROM stg_account
INNER JOIN department ON stg_account.ndept_id = department.ndept_id
INNER JOIN accountcpcmapping ON
    stg_account.naccount_cpc_mapping_id = accountcpcmapping.naccount_cpc_mapping_id
WHERE account.naccount_id   = stg_account.naccount_id
    AND account.ninst_id    = instID
    AND department.ninst_id = instID
    AND accountcpcmapping.ninst_id = instID
```